# A Set of Rational Numbers BMO1 Question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I came across a BMO problem:

Let S be a set of rational numbers with the following properties:

1. 1/2 is an element of S
2. If x is an element of S, then both 1/(x+1) is an element of S and x/(x+1) is an element of S

Prove that S contains all rational numbers in the interval 0 < x < 1.

My specific issue is understanding the proof, which starts by saying if x=(q-p)/p, where p and q are coprime integers and p < q < 2p, then 1/(x+1) = p/q.  Also, if x=p/(q-p), where p and q are coprime integers and 2p < q, then x/(x+1) = p/q. My question is why would the interval be p < q < 2p and 2p < q in both cases.

Comment: Please post the entire proof you refer to, exactly as written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are the constraints placed on $p, q$ by the writer of the proof. If you mean why from a logical point of view then it is done so $0 < x < 1$ holds.
$$0<x<1 \iff 0 < (q-p)/p < 1 \iff 0< q - p < p \iff p < q < 2p$$
It's similar to the other constraint.